# What is the minimum distance between two civil airplanes parked in a hangar?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-storing

When parking two airplanes in the hangar, what is minimum safe distance between them?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Are you asking about airliners, or any civil aircraft? If you look in a shared hangar at a GA airport, you'll often see aircraft packed in with only a few centimeters between them (and between them and the walls).

Comment: Minimum safe distance == "not touching"

Comment: Yaa , for airlines. Is there any besic rules to them on hanger.

Comment: @casey you should have linked this video with your "[not touching](https://youtu.be/otCpCn0l4Wo?t=14s)" :D

Comment: Contact between aircraft in large hangars used to be quite common. We used to refer to minor scrapes as "hangar rash."

Comment: As a student pilot, when I completed my 3-stop, long solo flight, I returned to the FBO after hours.  The hardest part of the entire flight was parking my plane back in its spot, by myself, with less than 2 inches of room on each wing.  **If it fits, it fits.**

Answer (score 7):

If you look at some civil-aircraft hangars, you will see that the planes are almost touching each other, as you can see here:

[image: Civil aircraft hangar]

The planes are so close to each other to fit a maximum amount of planes into a hangar.

There are different types of hangars. Some are built just to store aircraft when they aren't used, some are built for aircraft-maintenance-operations and can even contain robots. Hangars can be simple buildings with a big and open space or they can be very complex facilities.

If you want more infos about aircraft hangars take a look [here](https://www.wbdg.org/design/aviation_hangar.php).

You can find the minimum separation distances between aircraft and minimum distances between the aircraft and other obstructions [here](https://www.wbdg.org/ccb/browse_doc.php?d=3591)

Take a look at this table from [this](http://wbdg.org/ccb/AF/AFH/ARCHIVES/32_1084.pdf) document (page 30):

[image: Minimum safe distance]

As you can see, the minimum distance between the wings from two parked aircraft is not always the same.

> Dimensions vary for different models and configurations of aircraft.

If you want to find out the min. distance of an A380, you need to take a look at the documents provided by Airbus.

**No**, there is no basic rule. The safe distance is determined by the aircraft-type, configuration and the hangar (owner).

If the airliners are stored in the hangar, they can be pretty close to each other. However, maintenance of a big airliners takes up a lot of space:

[image: A380 Maintenance]

Comment: What's a _roboter_?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I'm sorry, I misspelled "robot". " roboter" is german for "robots".

Comment: When stacking planes vertically, make at least sure an deflated tire will not lead to a contact. It is prudent to leave a little more space than "not touching".

Comment: @PeterKämpf By "stacking planes vertically" you mean placing them on top of each other? How can we achieve that without physical contact?

Comment: @jklingler e.g. by placing a high-wing aircraft close to a low-wing aircraft so that the wings of the former overhang the latter, or a small aircraft under the wing of a much larger one.

Comment: @DanHulme I see, thank you :)

Comment: @DanHulme and here I was thinking hanging them from the ceiling ;)

Comment: The AF Block dimensions cover the space needed on the ramp, not in the hangar. Block space is sufficient to allow aircraft to taxi in and out of position as well as provide for maintenance/service vehicles. Inside AF hangars, I've seen both less space where it's primarily just parking to much more space where there's heavy maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

"Don't hit the other planes. Don't hit the walls. Don't hit anything else in the hangar." - that's the minimum safe distance.

There may be other requirements (e.g. by fire code: the number of aircraft stored in a hangar may be restricted by the amount of fuel each aircraft holds, and by the hangar's fire suppression capabilities).

Similarly in a hangar where active maintenance is happening the space between each aircraft may be larger to allow maintenance personnel access to each aircraft.

Comment: Sometimes the wings will overlap, with a high wing plane's wing over those of a low wing plane.

Comment: and with gliders, you'll see them all with one wing on the ground and one wing in the air, all tilted the same way, with sandbags on the low wing.